# How unset multiple session variables

Tags: php

What is the best way to unset multiple session variables? I am using unset ($_SESSION["q1"]); to clear the value of a session variable. However, I have 25 to code: q1 to q25 inclusive and I think there must be a better way than to write the unset code 25 times. I do not want to unset all variables because I want to keep the logged in user details. Thanks for any pointers

Comment: xy problem.. you should have stored them in an array, i.e `$_SESSION["q"][1]`, then you could simply do `unset($_SESSION["q"]);`, now you will need to arbitrarily loop over say 0 to `count($_SESSION)`, and use the iterator number to do `isset($_SESSION["q$i"])? unset(..)` etc

Comment: A loop won't do?

Comment: @ Lawrence Cherone, thanks for your input, I am a php beginner so I probably designed the system wrong, so based on your comments I will do some more research.